# Ubutu 16.10: Sound plays through built-in speaker when headphones connected

Tags: pulseaudio, 16.10, alsa, headphones, inspiron

I have a new Dell Inspiron 15 5578 with Ubuntu Studio 16.10 and Windows 10 (dual boot).  Everything works fine in Windows 10.  Initially, there was no sound at all coming out of the headphones when I plugged them in when booted into Ubuntu.  So far, I have installed  Ubuntu Desktop and tweaked `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf`  The updated settings there are:

```
[Element Headset]
required-any = any
switch = on
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right

[Element Line HP Swap]
switch = off
volume = off

[Element Speaker]
switch = mute
volume = ignore
```

I am now to the point where there actually is audio coming out of the headphones, thank goodness, but there are still a couple of remaining issues which I have been unable to resolve.  All of my attempts at further tweaking the analog-output-headphones.conf have resulted in no sound coming out of the headphones at all.  The remaining issues are:

1. When I plug in the headphone jack, there is still sound coming out of the speaker.
2. Whenever I try to use a program which uses Alsa directly, such as JACK or Audacity, the usage of alsa does something to the settings which makes it so the sound no longer goes out of the headphones.  When that happens, I need to reboot to get the headphones back working.

I have a feeling that these two issues are related and that there is still something wrong at the ALSA level.  Let's focus on the first one though.  If the second one is still an issue at that point, I'll open a different question for it.

Update - at this point, I now have everything working.  It turns out that it was not actually using the snd_hda_codec_realtek module.  I ended up adding the following line to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

```
install snd_hda_codec_realtek /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd_hda_codec_realtek
```

With this change, I was actually able to undo all of the changes to analanalog-output-headphones.conf.  Now everything is working as expected.  I also found that the ALSA problem was because the non-existent headset microphone was being selected as the input device.  This is now also resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The only change I needed to make this work was to add the following line to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf:

```
install snd_hda_codec_realtek /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd_hda_codec_realtek
```